# Covariance of two $t$-statistics

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

This question came up in a discussion about statistical tests in natural language processing (I'm happy to give you the full story if you are interested).

Suppose we have random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots$ and $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$
All $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are Bernoulli distributed n with the same success probability $p$. The $X_i$ are independent, and the $Y_i$ are independent, but there may be dependencies between the $X_i$ and $Y_i.$

Define the averages $\overline{X}^n = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, $\overline{Y}^n = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ and the $t$-statistics
$$
S^n = \sqrt{n} \frac{\overline{X}^n - p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}},
\qquad
T^n = \sqrt{n} \frac{\overline{Y}^n - p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}}.
$$
The central limit theorem guarantees that $S^n$ and $T^n$ converge in distribution to random variables $S, T \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1).$

Suppose that there is a convergent sequence $(c_n)_n$ such that $\text{Cov}(S^n, T^n) = c_n$.
Is it true that
$$
\text{Cov}(S,T) = \lim_n c_n ?
$$

I tried to apply dominated convergence, but failed to find a suitable dominating random variable.

Comment: Checking that $(S_n)$ and $(T_n)$ are bounded in $L^4$ would suffice. And indeed they are. (Unrelated: Why the funny looking exponents $n$ instead of indices?)

Comment: Why $L^4$? How do I proceed from $|ST| \le (|S|^2 + |T|^2)/2$? (The upper index notation is a bad habit from game theory...)

Comment: I reread more carefully your question and my first comment does not apply, sorry for the noise. With no dependence hypothesis on $(S,T)$, one cannot be sure that $\mathrm{Cov}(S_n,T_n)\to\mathrm{Cov}(S,T)$. For example, it might happen that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent for every $n$ and that $S=T$, then $c_n=0$ does not converge to $\mathrm{Cov}(S,T)=\mathrm{Var}(S)=1$.